# Passing multiple parameters to python in GNU parallel

Tags: python, parameters, gnu-parallel

I have code which works perfectly, but I want to use GNU parallel adn make it run faster.
The code reads in a file which has a JSON on every line, parses it and creates one more line.

Input (json.in)

```
{"NBR": "8001474830", "UNIQUE_ID": "PP007.8001474830.20150807"}
```

Output

```
{"create": {"_type": "transaction", "_id":"PP007.8001474830.20150807.8001474830", "_index": "DB_order"}}

{"NBR": "8001474830:, "UNIQUE_ID": "PP007.8001474830.20150807"}
```

The python code is as follows:

```
import sys
import json
import fileinput

index = ""+sys.argv[2]+""
type = ""+sys.argv[3]+""


create_bulk={ "create":  { "_index": index, "_type": type, "_id": "0"}}

for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[1]):
        json_in=json.loads(line)
        create_bulk["create"]["_id"]=json_in["UNIQUE_ID"]+"."+json_in["NBR"]
        print json.dumps(create_bulk)
        print json.dumps(json_in)
```

I execute the code as follows

```
python json_parser.py json.in DB_order transaction
```

My question is how do I convert this to GNU parallel syntax.

I'm able to amke it work in GNU parallel just by passing file name like this:

> parallel --pipepart -a json.in --block 1M python json_parser.py

But how do I pass the other two parameters DB_order and transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--fifo` is very efficient:

```
parallel --pipepart --fifo -a json.in --block 1M python json_parser.py {} my_DB_order my_transaction
```

I notice you do not use `-k`, so I assume the order does not matter in which case this is typically faster:

```
parallel --round-robin --pipepart --fifo -a json.in python json_parser.py {} DB_ordera transactiona
```

It computes `--block` as filesize/jobslots and gives one block to each job. The benefit: Fewer job startups. The downside: If one block is much slower, it may slow everything down. Say, if a block takes twice the time to process as the others, then the total runtime will be twice as long.

A compromise between `--block 1M` and `--roundrobin` is to leave out `--block`. This will make GNU Parallel compute `--block` as  filesize/(10*jobslots) resulting in 10 jobs per jobslot. If one block takes twice as the rest, then runtime will only be 10% longer.

Comment: Ole thanks for building GNU parallel and taking time to answer questions!!